# Blender smoke sim explosion just ends up like volumetric fog

Tags: smoke-simulation

I was following a tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=29yfS-icS3M&t=564s&ab_channel=Iridesium) on explosions in blender but i've run into a few problems. I followed it pretty much exactly, though he does go a bit fast so I may have missed a thing or two. Around 15:03 after he does the initial baking he selects a frame and goes into rendered view before adjusting the shaders, and his smoke already looks like how it should, just without the colors. However when I enter rendered view after baking, all I see is a cube of smoke filling the entire domain, rather than a frame from the explosion. Basically like how volumetric fog looks in eevee.

Also earlier when he's in solid view he turns on color mapping to see the smoke better, and it makes his smoke white, but when i do it I see a bunch of separated black globs. When I turn off color mapping I don't even see anything at all

He's on 2.82.7 and i'm on 2.9 but unless they've completely changed the way smoke sims work i don't think that is the problem.

What it should look like:
[image]

What I got:
[image]

Material nodes:
[image]

Blend File: https://drive.google.com/file/d/147q_6xxkBdWAqRlkRWM8qnoQfSP_ELbx/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please edit your question to include images of what you're describing - instead of relying on someone downloading your Blend file. This makes the question more accessible to others so that they can see the problem and associated solution. Also, use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to share your blend file instead of other sites to ensure it remains accessible (it's the 'official' place to upload blend files for this site).

Comment: I know about giantcow, site was down yesterday when i was trying to post this. Will add some images

Comment: Add an image of the material  nodes for the smoke domain

Comment: I highly doubt that is making the difference, because mine already looks different before we add any material at all, but i've added it. Basically just a default principled volume node.

Comment: That's the problem. Which instructions did you follow that just added a Principled Volume as the material? Have you done any research how one shades smoke in Blender?`

Comment: Ah I missed the part where he changed the volume info node to density. Also got a bit confused because the guy in the tutorial said he wasn't going to bake noise yet but then ended up baking the noise. I've now baked the noise as well and its looking more like how its supposed to. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell the Principled Volume node where to get it's measure of the 'density' of the domain from. You can do this by either feeding a value into the 'Density' socket or you can fill in the 'Density Attribute' to indicate it should be taken from the smoke domain 'density' attribute.

In your case you should be able to simply click on the 'Density Attribute' field and enter 'density' (all lower case).

[image: principled volume density attribute]

Changing the 'Density' value (just above the Density Attribute) will adjust overall density of the smoke (it acts as a multiplier).

Comment: This helped me find the problem. In the tutorial I was watching the guy deleted the density attribute and adds a volume info with a colorRamp and math node, hence why I had nothing in that box. Only thing is when I added the volume info I forgot to use the density instead of the color output.